# how to insert data from texboxes to datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datasource, datarow

I want to make a phone book and need to add contact information from text boxes to
data grid view.

Below is my code

**Problem with it is** that each time after first row fills - it doesn't new rows anymore.

```
 class information
{
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    public string surname { get; set; }
    public int phonenumber { get; set; }
    public int cellphone { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }

}
```

how can use this class in my code?

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataRow dr;

dt.Columns.Add("Firstname");
dt.Columns.Add("Lastname");
dt.Columns.Add("PhoneNumber");

dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["Firstname"] = tb1.Text;
dr["Lastname"] = tb2.Text;
dr["PhoneNumber"] = tb3.Text;

dt.Rows.Add(dr);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: where did you write this code? in which method?

Comment: I have searched in net and found it in some webpages. how come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the lack of information provided, I am going to assume that the error you are getting is due to a new DataTable every time and replaced it in the 
DataGridView's datasource. What you really want to do is create only one DataTable, attach it to the DataSource and add to that table every time. See the code below

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Insert the columns you require
        dt.Columns.Add("Firstname");
        dt.Columns.Add("Lastname");
        dt.Columns.Add("PhoneNumber");

        // This is the only time you need to attach to the DataSource
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt; 
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Add a new row 
        var dr = dt.Rows.Add();

        // And attach the values to the appropriate column
        dr["Firstname"] = tb1.Text;
        dr["Lastname"] = tb2.Text;
        dr["PhoneNumber"] = tb3.Text;
    }

    private void DeleteRow()
    {
        if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            dt.Rows[dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index].Delete();
            return;
        }

        if (dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
        {
            dt.Rows[dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex].Delete();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but I have another question.

Comment: how can I delete a row?

Comment: You need to find the index of the row you want to delete and call dt.Rows[RowIndex].Delete();

Comment: how can I find the index?

Comment: how can I find the index of the row?

Comment: @user3114521 For delete: You can add 1 column in your `Dt["id"]` which is unique and auto generated and then using RowClick of `dataGrid` 
You can delete from dt and Bind it to grid

Comment: @user3114521 check the doe above, I have added a method which shows how you can retrieve the row index.

Answer (score 3):

I would do it something like this:

```
private void PopulateGridView()
{
    var myRecords = new List<PhoneBookRecord>();
    myRecords.Add(new PhoneBookRecord { FirstName = "blah", LastName = "Blah", PhoneNumber = "1234" });
    myRecords.Add(new PhoneBookRecord { FirstName = "New", LastName = "Song", PhoneNumber = "132134" });
    temper.DataSource = myRecords; 
}

class PhoneBookRecord
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because of

```
dr = dt.NewRow();
```

You have to check whether datatable has data or not, if it had then you have to 
assign as follows

```
dr = dt.Rows.Add();
```

**For eg:**

```
if(ViewState("temp") == null)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataRow dr;
    dt.Columns.Add("Firstname");
    dt.Columns.Add("Lastname");
    dt.Columns.Add("PhoneNumber");
    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["Firstname"] = tb1.Text;
    dr["Lastname"] = tb2.Text;
    dr["PhoneNumber"] = tb3.Text;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt; 
    ViewState("temp")=dt;
}
else
{
    DataTable dt = ViewState("temp")
    DataRow dr;
    dr =dt.Rows.Add();
    dr["Firstname"] = tb1.Text;
    dr["Lastname"] = tb2.Text;
    dr["PhoneNumber"] = tb3.Text;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt; 
    ViewState("temp")=dt;
}
```

Comment: would please tell me how can I check whether my data table has data or not?

Comment: Please check with my solution.This part checks that. if ViewState("temp")= nothing

Comment: @Vignesh Kumar you code will fail to compile for two reasons, 1) comparison in C# are done using ==, 2) the word 'nothing' is a VB thing where C# uses null.

Comment: @MPatel Thanks mate. I have Updated solution.

Comment: can you tell me. 1) how can I delete a row?   2) how can I use my class information?

Comment: Use dt.Rows.Remove(dr)

Comment: I have made a class for my phone book. as you can see in my codes. now I don't know how to use my class in my phone book's code.

Comment: You need to create object for that class and need to access those property using Object

Comment: can you explain more or write the code for me? I am a little bit new in C#

Comment: Information  in = new Information();
    in.firstname =txtFirstname.text;

Comment: aha I remembered that. but is it good to use class in this code?

Comment: @sesideh i think you dont need here

Answer (score 1):

try THIS:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataRow dr;      

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add("Firstname");
        dt.Columns.Add("Lastname");
        dt.Columns.Add("PhoneNumber");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Firstname"] = textBox1.Text;
        dr["Lastname"] = textBox2.Text;
        dr["PhoneNumber"] = textBox3.Text;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;     
    }
}
```